# Angularjs databinding between factory and view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope, factory

I'm having some trouble with databinding in AngularJS.
In short I'm trying to link a variable from my factory to my view (the $scope).
The factory (in my full implementation) listens to specific broadcasts and updates the variable, and the view should reflect this change, but it doesn't.

I managed to seperate the problem from much of the other code. The function the controller calls   (setTrue) is just a placeholder for some more difficult backend action.

When running the code, I would expect to see "true" written in the view. I have no idea why the view remains "false"?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Fact">
        value: {{model}}<br/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller('Fact', ['$scope','Fact', function ($scope, Fact) {
          $scope.model = Fact.data;
          Fact.setTrue();
        }]);

        app.factory("Fact", function () {
            var Fact = {};
            Fact.data = false;

            Fact.setTrue = function () {
                Fact.data = true;
            };

            return Fact;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IIq2H4gW1DBoe5zVPx0g

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

**edit:**

When I change the above code to have

```
$scope.model = Fact;
```

and

```
value: {{model.data}}
```

It suddenly works... but I don't like having to put my whole factory in my $scope.

Comment: Booleans are passed by value, not by reference

Comment: Why are you opposed to placing the factory object in the scope? this is the correct way to do this, when you create a factory it is a singleton object, and it should be used set scope values

Comment: @JaredReeves If I just put the factory in the $scope, then I don't really see the point of having a controller?

Comment: @JoseM Yeah I see. I've wrapped the return in a simple object, and now the data-binding is working. Thanks

Comment: @user3319803 the point of having a controller is that is the place you manipulate the model, but the factory is singleton object that you can use in multiple controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know the following code snippet will work correctly. As you can see I am assigning the returned singleton to a scope value. From this I can thin call all of the returned methods from the factory on this new scope object.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'Fact',
    function($scope, Fact) {
      $scope.model = Fact;
      $scope.model.setTrue();
    }
  ]).factory("Fact", function() {
    var Fact = {};
    Fact.data = false;

    Fact.setTrue = function() {
      Fact.data = true;
    };

    return Fact;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    value: {{model.data}}
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case I think this would be the correct way to accomplish what you are wanting. I assume you could think of other scenarios where a factory would have a large number of associated, and it would be useful that have access to the whole object in your controller.

In the following code snippet I have wrapped the Boolean value in an object and assigned like you were to the scope, but now any changes will be bound the the $scope.model object.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'Fact',
    function($scope, Fact) {
      $scope.model = Fact.data
      Fact.setTrue();
      //$scope.model.setTrue();
    }
  ]).factory("Fact", function() {
    var Fact = {};
    Fact.data = {"value":false};

    Fact.setTrue = function() {
      Fact.data.value = true;
    };

    return Fact;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    value: {{model.value}}
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

However if you do not want to do it this way and are only wanting to assign the data value to the scope, you need to change the Fact factory before you assign the value to the scope or wrap it in an object that then will pass a reference instead of a value. It should be noted that in your code you were assigning a Boolean value to the $scope.model, however it is not bond to the Fact.data, adn thus any changes to Fact will not effect the model object.

Comment: Your second approach is what I ended up using. So wrapping it in an object. Do you think a certain approach is better then the other?

Comment: It really depends on the implementation. I kind of like the second approach better because it lets you call the functions on factory rather then a new object, this is especially true if your data was a more complex object(say user object) that you then bind a few of the properties to the scope.

Comment: Please Note that you will run into other cases where you will need to wrap a Boolean value in an object to get binding to work, one case I can think of is ng-if.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite surprised with the way you are using the factory.

Are you not supposed to do something more like :

```
(function() {
 angular.module("services")
.factory("dataService", function ($http) {

  var data = "";

  var getData = function() {
    return data;
  }

  var setData = function(newData) {
    data = newData;
  }

  return {
    getData: getData,
    setData: setData
  };

});
```

})();

and then you just have to call in your controller

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
      $scope.model.data = dataService.getData();
      dataService.setData("something");
    }]);
```

Comment: The notation you're using is also possible. I was just following some tutorials and that way of writing was shown there. 
But (as far as I understand) you shouldn't be using getters and setters in Angular, just use the automatic databinding.

Comment: @sam are you sure this works? Because `data = newData;` will destroy the data binding and the scope of the controller won't update.
I think this only works with `angular.extend(data, newData);`